# Are class skill bonuses per rank or only once?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

A skill gets a +3 bonus if it's a class skill.  Do you only get the bonus once, or do you get the bonus for every rank put into the skill?

Comment: If you think you've answered your own question and that it will help others, you can add an answer below it instead of editing the question. It's completely OK to answer your own question once you've figured something out! Alternatively, if you don't think this will help others in the future, you can simply delete the question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie is correct, but Tom M cannot add the answer he found unless this is reopened, so voting to reopen. Not the most interesting question, but a valid one. Just don't include the answer you found as an edit to the question, add it as an answer.

Comment: @KRyan I suspect Tom is long-gone and not going to return—being too busy happily rolling skill checks correctly, no doubt. :) When it reopens, feel free to add the answer yourself rather than wait.

Answer (score 11):

You only get these bonuses once, the first time you put a rank into the skill (or the first time you take a level in a class that has it as a class skill, if you’d already had ranks in it).

Source: [Pathfinder SRD – Class Skills](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Class-Skills)

Comment: If someone actually goes and cites the relevant rules, that would make a better answer and I'll upvote that.

Comment: Better added right there!